# Solving a probability problem/putting reccurance in closed form

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a (infinite) ladder, with a cone on rung 0, and you have a coin. Each time you flip the coin, if you get tails you move the cone up the ladder 1 spot, heads you move it up two spots. What is the probability of the cone landing on the nth rung? I have this down to a recurrence relation

$$P_n =1/2( P_{n-1} + P_{n-2})$$

But I am not sure how to proceed. Expanding seems to produce something useful in terms of binomial coefficients, but it does not fully solve the recurrence relation.

Apologies for forgotten factor of 1/2!

Comment: It seems like you may want to consider a recurrence in 2 variables, one variable for the number of flips, and one variable for the location on the ladder.  So, for example, if $n$ is the probability of landing on the $n$th rung, and $m$ is the number of coin flips, you'd have:  $P(n,k) = P(n-1,k-1)/2+P(n-1,k-2)/2$.  Does this make sense?  I can write this up further if you'd like...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditioning on the value of the rung visited before rung $n$ I get the recurrence $P_n=P_{n-1}/2+P_{n-2}/2$. The characteristic equation of this linear recurrence is $x^2-x/2-1/2$ with roots $1,-1/2$ giving general solution $P_n=A+B(-1/2)^n$. Substituting initial conditions $P_0=1,P_1=1/2$ gives $P_n=2/3+(1/3)(-1/2)^n$.

For what it's worth here is a short R simulation

```
p <- function(n)2/3+(1/3)*(-.5)^n
res <- replicate(1e4,{
    r <- sample(0:1,20,replace=T)
    7 %in% cumsum(r+1)
})
mean(res)
[1] 0.6648
p(7)
[1] 0.6640625
```